# Java: Count the occurence of each element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, count

I am writing a program where I make an array of 100 integer elements with random integer elements from numbers 0 to 20. I was told to write a method that counts how many times each value 0 to 20 is generated. I have tried to write this part of the code, but nothing is working. Can someone please help me fix what I am doing wrong? Here is my code I have been working on.

```
public static void arrayCounter()
{
    int[] counter = new int[21];
    for (int x = 0; x < counter.length; x++)
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++)
        {    
            if (i == randomArray[x])
            counter[x]++;     
        }
        System.out.println("Element " + x + " : " + counter[x] + " times");
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagine someone unknown is coming to show, show you some code and says *"nothing is working"*. What would you think? Would you think "ah, I understand what she expects to get, what she currently gets and why this is wrong" or would you think "can please explain your problem instead"?

Answer (score 1):

You are over thinking this, you don't need a nested loop to access each element of an array, you just need an index.

```
public static int[] count(int[] array, int maxValue) {
    int[] count = new int[maxValue + 1];
    // for each value.
    for (int n : array) count[n]++; // increment the counter for that value.
    return count;
}
```

You can call this with

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] array = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) array[i] = rand.nextInt(21);

int[] count = count(array, 20);
for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
    System.out.println(i + ": " + count[i]);
```

running it here http://ideone.com/utSNd3 prints

```
0: 5
1: 5
2: 4
3: 6
4: 4
5: 9
6: 5
7: 9
8: 1
9: 3
10: 4
11: 11
12: 2
13: 6
14: 1
15: 6
16: 5
17: 3
18: 4
19: 4
20: 3
```

Comment: When I tried this in my code, my program won't load. How will I be able to print this?

Comment: @Alyssa I have added an example of how to call this and print the result.

Comment: @Alyssa A comment on your profile; You will realise as you learn more than there is far more to learn than one person can.  You learn how to work when you can't know everything.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with

```
if (x == randomArray[i])
```

and not

```
if (i == randomArray[x])
```

An other solution :
Stop using array.
You can use stream if you have Java 8 or Collection with Java 6+ this should works :

```
Set<T> mySet = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(someArray));
int occurrences = Collections.frequency(mySet, x);
```

Just add a cycle for testing each value of x

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a variable `int count` like this:

```
 int count =0;
 for (int x = 0; x < counter.length; x++)
     {            
    for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++)
    {    
        if (randomArray[i] == randomArray[x])
        count++;     
       }
     }

    System.out.println("Element " + x + " : " + count + " times");
```

Comment: You don't need a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

another more dynamic solution could be the usage of a `Map` to identify how often which value appears. It´s basicly the same priniciple that @PeterLawray uses, but instead of using an `array` with an index that defines the value, where you need to know the max value of the array first,  this solution does use the `key` of the `map` to indentify each value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] testArray = {0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 15, 1, 2, 3, 5};
    count(testArray);
}

public static void count(int[] array) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int i : array) {
        // If the value was already found, increase it´s occurence, 
        // otherwise the value occured once yet, so we put 1 in there
        counter.put(i, counter.get(i) == null ? 1 : counter.get(i) + 1 );
    }
    for(Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : counter.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("The value " + entry.getKey() + " appears " + entry.getValue() + " times");
    }
}
```